# How to fix erorr Invalid hook call react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm new to react and I am facing the problem that show Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component, I've check the React and React Dom version but it the same nothing problem .

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route ,Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
//Pages
import Header from './Pages/Header'
import List from './Pages/List';

function App() {
  return (
<Router>
   <Container>
<div className="App">

   <div className="Content">
      <Routes>
      <Route path="../src/Pages/List.js" component={List} />
      </Routes>

   </div>

</div>
</Container>

</Router>

    /*<BrowserRouter>
   <Container>
   <Header />
   <Routes>

   <Route path="../src/Pages/List.js" components={List} />
   
   </Routes>
   
   </Container>
      </BrowserRouter>
   */
  );
}

export default App; ``'
```

Comment: What version of `react` and `react-dom` do you have installed? Run `npm list react react-dom` in your project and report back. React hooks were introduced in React v16.8.4 IIRC, so you need *at least* this version.

Comment: If it is past v16.8.4 , could you grab the exact location of which this error occurs? Most likely is within a component

Comment: "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",

Comment: Well, you've a new enough version of React, and `App` isn't using any React hooks. Any idea what component is being referred to? Is it in `List`? What is the full error message? Is there a stacktrace?